# Strange TextView behavior - floating letters

Tags: android, textview

How to avoid following behavior of TextView?

[image: you need to see picture to understand question]

Update. I just found that this problem appears when I use custom font http://www.ephifonts.com/free-helvetica-font-helvetica-neue-bold.html
This font doesn't contains cyrillic symbols.

Comment: Post your xml  layout with the textview

Comment: Maybe it's the difference in the font?